# OpenBase server database connection troubleshoot?

Tags: database, database-performance, not-responding

I am troubleshooting a workstation/server instance in which an application hangs while interacting with our Windows 2003 Server OpenBase-hosted database.

In short, the application will go into "Not Responding" for 45-seconds or more while doing certain functions.

I'm hoping for some general ideas on how to troubleshoot what the application is waiting for exactly. Other workstations that run this software in the environment don't exhibit the problem but our server is definitely a little worse-for-wear.

I'd like to find out things like: Is the program waiting for a response from the database server? Has the desktop antivirus stepped in front of the application?

The answer may be: Keep poking with Process Explorer and Process Monitor.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run [Windows Performance Analyzer Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162945.aspx) on the client, perform the action that creates the problem, and analyze it.

If nothing is obvious on the client side, do the same thing on the server side, but when you only have a single client connecting - otherwise you'll a *great deal* of noise to work through.

ProcMon can help too, but that's tough to really analyze.

Comment: Oh! This sounds great. I'll let ya know how it goes!